# How use grep for that complicated expressions?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

```
+----+-------+-----+ 
| ID | STORE | QTY |
+----+-------+-----+
|    |       |     |
| 9  | 101   | 18  |
|    |       |     |
| 8  | 154   | 19  |
|    |       |     |
| 7  | 111   | 13  |
|    |       |     |
| 9  | 154   | 18  |
|    |       |     |
| 8  | 101   | 19  |
|    |       |     |
| 7  | 101   | 13  |
|    |       |     |
| 9  | 111   | 18  |
|    |       |     |
| 8  | 111   | 19  |
|    |       |     |
| 7  | 154   | 14  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Suppose that I have 3 stores, and I'd like to take STORE for every id which qty is the same for every store.

e.g id 9 is in 3 stores, in every store has 18 qty,
but id 7 is in stores but in only two store has equal qty (in store 111 and 101 - in 154 - id has 14 qty); how can I get that result using grep?

Do you think that is impossible to get that one in one expressions? I thought about regex but I don't know in which way I get Qty and compare to another row. In my file it looks like:

Comment: It seems like you got an output from a SQL database. Use SQL to query said database instead of using coreutils on the output.

Comment: are the `|`s part of your text or just fancy decoration for purpose of asking the question?

Comment: @Sundeep just fancy decoration in other to better read output

Comment: better to add actual input without decorative elements and expected output for clarity... also, see if `awk 'id[$1]=$0{if($3 != qty[$1]) delete id[$1]} {qty[$1]=$3} END{for (i in id) {print id[i]}}' file` works

Answer (score 0):

Extract the first and last columns by `cut`, count the number of uniq combinations, and output only those whose count is 3 (i.e. the value is the same for all three stores):

```
$ cut -d\| -f2,4 | sort | uniq -c | grep '^ *3 '
      3  8  | 19  
      3  9  | 18
```